# Definite integration of tanx with lower limit a and upper limit b using method of limit of a sum

Tags: calculus

We all know that sinx and cosx can be easily integrated using ab initio or method of summation between limits a & b. But sinx/cosx=tanx cannot be integrated by this method. Why? Is it that difficult to find that limit or is it impossible? 
Using substitution method we can easily find that integral of tanx is log(secx) but using the method of limit of sum this cant be obtained

Comment: What makes you think that it cannot be evaluated from definition? It's tedious if that's what you mean, but never impossible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like to show that $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^N \tan\left(\frac{ix}{N}\right) = \ln(\sec x)$$  for any $x$ with $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.  If so, have you tried?

Comment: Yeah but how will the series converge to ln(secx) when n tends to infinity. Plz show me the whole process if u could